Navisworks to SVF - reduce size of properties?
When translation a NWD to SVF, is there a way to reduce the final size of the property DB for the SVF?
I am struggling to fetch the properties because the file is too big and was wondering if I could drop properties in the original NWD to reduce size?

These are the only options you have when translating NWD to SVF:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/jobs/job-POST/#body-structure

You could try if not extracting those properties (materials and timeline) makes a difference.
Another option might be reducing the number of properties inside Navisworks, but to check about that it would be best to post a question on the Navisworks forum: 
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/navisworks-forum/bd-p/372
